# Who was responsible for the Apple business practice of taking back old hardware when selling the new stuff?

Tags: apple

I have been told and I have read that old Apple computers like the Lisa are pretty hard to come by. The Lisa was a bit over-priced, had limited software and just was generally outclassed by the Macintosh.

What also affected why these things are rare today is the age-old practice that the Apple company has of taking back old hardware for a discount on the new. Who came up with this idea? I was just wondering who came up with that business model?

Comment: Maybe rephrase this question so it seems less like a rant?

Comment: Apple never forced anyone to give them back hardware they’d bought; where did that idea come from? Being offered a discount if you part-exchange old hardware for new doesn’t mean you have to upgrade.

Comment: For one it was only done with apple 1 to Apple II transition - useful to keep in mind that the Apple II originally wasn't a huge success. More important, trade ins have always been a sales tool. Why should computers be different from car dealers offering a discount for trading-in last years car to sell the newest model. A well proven way to crank up early or recover weak sales. It's not self sabotage, but promotion. Apple doesn't earn money from satisfied customers using their old machine for decades, they are about selling new ones - like any other manufacturing business. No racket to be seen

Comment: Was it compulsory to return the old gear?  If not, it seems little different than the fairly common 'trade in your old phone for a discount on a new one' offer seen today. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @davidbak - I have made an edit.

Comment: Back in the 1970s it was not uncommon to take old working industrial instruments when new ones were sold and to destroy them so they wouldn't dilute market value. I don't think Apple innovated that practice.

Answer (score 0):

The practice goes back to the introduction of the Apple II.  The Apple I was sufficiently expensive that Apple would have been expected to produce assistance to purchasers, but the only people at Apple who would be able to provide assistance were the founders, who would rather be working on new designs.  If an Apple I owner would have needed one hour of assistance over the lifetime of a product, there would likely have only been two people who would have been able to provide it--Steve Wozniak and Steve Jobs--because the installed base of the Apple I would have been too small to justify training anyone else to provide assistance.

It would be interesting to know if anyone other than Apple Computer ever constructed any expansion boards for the Apple I, and if so whether they continued to use the Apple I after the Apple II came out.  It would not seem implausible that someone might have bought an Apple I for use as an industrial process controller, and then built an expansion card to interface with their industrial process.  In that one specific scenario, an Apple I *might* be superior to an Apple II.  In all other scenarios, however, a one-for-one swap between an Apple I and an Apple II would have benefited everybody involved.

Comment: theory is plausible but is there any documentary evidence?

Comment: I've seen interviews with Woz where he mentioned that he wanted the Apple I to disappear.  I don't recall him specifically saying that such attitude was a result of having to handle support requests, but it would be hard to imagine many situations where any effort spent on Apple I support couldn't have been better spent getting a customer running with an Apple II.  The second paragraph is conjecture, but is intended to acknowledge that it wouldn't be entirely impossible for someone to receive more benefit from Apple I support than they could receive from Apple II support.

Comment: yeah it was the first paragraph I was thinking of.  maybe I'll go look for that Woz interview, sounds interesting

Comment: As a programmer who sometimes has to deal with the more refractory customer problems, I too wish older versions (in my case, of software) would just disappear.  This does not seem particularly remarkable.

Comment: As a programmer who also sometimes has to deal with the more refractory customer problems, I too wish that _newer_ versions (in my case, of software) would just disappear.  Usually I feel this right after certain ... problematic ... deployments ...